# 3 (six-sided) dice are rolled. What is the probability that the sum of the numbers is less than or equal to 5?

Tags: probability

I understand simpler probability problems, but got tripped up with this one. Please explain your work if possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can just start by calculating the probability of the sum equal to 3, then 4, then 5. And add them all up.

Answer (score 2):

The sum can be either 3, 4, or 5.

If the sum is 3, the dice must be $1, 1, 1$, with probability $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$

If the sum is 4, the dice must be $1, 1, 2$. This dice rolls can be $1,2,1$ or $2,1,1$ (ordering), so the probability is $\displaystyle 3\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$

If the sum is 5, the dice must be $1, 1, 3$ or $1, 2, 2$, similarly both cases have probability $3\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3$.

So, the total probability is $\displaystyle \boxed{\frac{10}{216}}$.